# Gnuplot surface grid only in showing in the x-direction, why not y direction?

Tags: gnuplot

I have quite a lot of data that I would like to visualize in a 3d surface grid. When I

```
splot "surface.csv" u 1:2:7 w p lc rgb "black" ps 0.2
```

I get this

[image]

When I

```
splot "surface.csv" u 1:2:7 w l lc rgb "black"
```

I get this

[image]

I would like to have lines connecting all data points in both the x and y direction. Surely this is possible?

What might I do to achieve the y-directional lines? My data file is organized like this (note that I may not have the same number of points within the same data block)

```
0 1 z1
0 2 z2
0 3 z3
.
.
.
0 n zn

20 1 z1
20 2 z2
20 3 z3
.
.
.
20 m zm

.
.
.
```

---

Error to Octave command:

```
octave:1> d=load('surfacefull.csv');
octave:2> [y i]=sort(d(:,2));
octave:3> d_t=d(:,i);
error: A(I,J): column index out of bounds; value 905 out of bound 6
octave:3> dlmwrite('surfacefull_t.csv',d_t," ");
error: 'd_t' undefined near line 1 column 30
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, I'm not sure which you were asking about.

**1)**
If you want to interpolate your data on a uniform grid then you'd use `dgrid3d`: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node177.html

Some examples are shown here: http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/dgrid3d.html

**2)**
If you want all your lines to intersect with lines without a uniform grid, as you have done so far, just transpose your data in octave (or matlab) so that the 2nd spacial dimension changes slowest then plot like

```
splot "surface.csv"   u 1:2:5 w l lc rgb "black", \
      "surface_t.csv" u 1:2:5 w l lc rgb "black"
```

If you link some data I'd be able to show an example

---

Below is done using the above plot command where the surface_t.csv file was transposed in Gnu Octave with something like

```
d=load('surfacefull.csv');
[y i]=sort(d(:,2));
d_t=d(i,:);
dlmwrite('surfacefull_t.csv',d_t," ");
```

I have a script to do the record spacing, but you can do that by hand.

[image]

Comment: Here's the data. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyz8iz7eert80cb/surfacefull.csv?dl=0
I found in the manual that the points cannot be connected in both directions when the data blocks are not all of similar size. But I thought I could just "stitch" them together, making a small overlap of data points. I have found that dgrid3d smoothes the data to the unrecognizable.

Comment: See my edit, you just need to swap the records manually to plot in the other direction

Comment: Running the Octave commands give me some errors, see original question. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "swap the records" or "do the record spacing".

Comment: Right, it should have been `d_t=d(i,:);`, I just edited the code block.  When you plot lines from a datafile in gnuplot, each point for a line is given by a row in your datafile (called a "record"). A blank row indicates that a new line should be started. You need to go through 'surfacefull_t.csv' and put a blank row where your desired line terminates, like I've done for the first couple lines here: http://pastebin.com/raw/ETD9NfX8 . I'd write a script to do this newline stuff if your data set is large.